# How best to load a sequence of images in a series with javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am thinking about loading a series of images one by one for the user in the browser.

Would I go about this by opening a socket and request the images one by one with a given (slow) interval? Or would you say "Why not just make it a video and use all the advantages that this already has for browsers"? (Since a video is also just a series of images)

I want to stress that I would like to get them in a slow interval, so hopefully it won't create any stress on the client or the server.

What would be the best way?

Comment: Load them, one by one, on a as-needed basis. But there's no general rule here - there are too many variables. I wouldn't recommend the video unless the timing of these things is predetermined as well (since if you can interact you now have to figure out at what currentTime some image you want to show is).

Comment: Whether a video is a better idea depends on what the images contain.